# Is there a place to find CSS files to customize MkDocs' Material Theme?

Tags: css, mkdocs

I currently use MkDocs together with the Material Theme, to create nice looking wiki and documentation pages.
However, I would like to customize the Theme to make it generally darker, as I'm not a big fan of bright white backgrounds. But sadly am I not good at all with customizing stuff through CSS (which seems to be the only way here) so I was wondering if there is a place/site, where I can find pre-defined CSS files to alter the theme of Material/MkDocs, to something I like.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there are not so many of them if at all (unlike the original MkDocs).
But if you are looking for a dark theme, you can quickstart with the [MkDocs-Material-Dark-Theme](https://github.com/markusressel/MkDocs-Material-Dark-Theme). 
For more advanced customizations, you do have to proceed with a [custom CSS](https://squidfunk.github.io/mkdocs-material/customization/#additional-stylesheets).

There are many tutorials on how to start with basic styling so you may find them useful doing your first steps. You can check CSS selectors in the [main CSS file](https://github.com/squidfunk/mkdocs-material/blob/master/src/assets/stylesheets/palette.scss) of the Material theme or use Developer tools in your browser. To play around with color combinations you can use [coolors.co](https://coolors.co/) or [flatuicolors.com](https://flatuicolors.com).